# What is being inherited by class flask.views.MethodView?

Tags: python, flask

Why are we passing `flask.views.MethodView` in the class?

`app.add_url_rule` > in this snippet, `add_url_rule` is  this something predefined property?

Similarly `view_func`, `View.as_view` > are they predefined?

```
import flask, flask.views
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return "Hello World!"

app.add_url_rule('/',view_func=View.as_view('main'))

app.debug = True
app.run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`View` is a *subclass* of the [`flask.views.MethodView` class](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.views.MethodView). The latter provides base functionality, like the [`as_view()` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.views.View.as_view):

> Converts the class into an actual view function that can be used with the routing system. Internally this generates a function on the fly which will instantiate the View on each request and call the `dispatch_request()` method on it.

Also see [Pluggable Views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/).

Because this is not a *function*-based view, you cannot use the `@app.route()` decorator on it. You use the alternative [`app.add_url_rule()` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) instead in that case:

> Connects a URL rule. Works exactly like the `route()` decorator. If a `view_func` is provided it will be registered with the endpoint.

`view_func` is a documented keyword argument for this method; when the registered path is requested (in your example `/`), then whatever `as_view()` returned is called by Flask. That in turn calls `dispatch_request()`, which then calls the `View().get()` method *if the HTTP request used a GET method*.